# Cleaning up multiple functions and lambdas in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, jupyter-notebook

My company tracks rejection issues in a 3rd party system. Any given ticket can have multiple reasons for rejection. My coworker exports the list of rejected tickets to an Excel file to ultimately use in data visualization.

I created a Jupyter Notebook file that will split out the reasons into individual columns which are true or false. There are currently 10 possible reasons, so I have 10 separate functions that check if each value is true, and run 10 separate lambdas. It works perfectly, but it is not very clean or maintainable.

I am struggling trying to find the right way (or even just a way that works) to combine all those functions and lambdas into a cleaner set of code.

I have a series of 10 functions, one for each reason, that are almost identical:

```
def reason_one (x):
    
    value = 0
    
    if 'reason_one' in x:
        value = 1
    else:
        pass
        
    return value
```

```
def reason_two (x):
    
    value = 0
    
    if 'reason_two' in x:
        value = 1
    else:
        pass
        
    return value
```

and so on, for all 10 reasons we currently use.

Then, I run 10 nearly identical lambdas, one after the other:

```
df['Reason One'] = df['Labels'].map(lambda x: reason_one(x))
```

```
df['Reason Two'] = df['Labels'].map(lambda x: verification(x))
```

Is there a way to clean this up? Ideally, I would like to create a dictionary that has all the reason codes and the columns they should be named, then loop through the Labels column on the dataframe for each possible value, adding a column each time.

I have my dictionary set up:

```
error_list = {
    'reason_one': 'Reason One',
    'reason_two': 'Reason Two',
    'reason_three': 'Reason Three',
    'reason_four': 'Reason Four'
}
```

I like this because my coworker would be able to just change that list and run the notebook and have everything work. For example, he might add a new reason; or edit the column name for a given reason code to be more clear.

My idea was to create a function that takes in a dictionary and a column, iterates over the dictionary keys, appends either 0 or 1 to and empty list, then use that list to create a new column.

I got this far:

```
def breakout_columns (errors, column):
    
    column_values = []
    
    for key in errors:
        
        if key in column:
            value = 1
        else:
            value = 0
        
        column_values.append(value)
    
        print(column_values)
```

That does indeed produce a list with 10 values when I run it, however they are all 0s even when some of them should be true. I was looking for resources on iterating over dataframe rows, and I am not seeing anything remotely like what I am trying to do.

Beyond this piece not working, I am concerned my approach is inherently flawed and either (a) I should be doing something completely different to try to clean things up; or (b) what I am trying to do is not possible or does not make sense, so I need to just stick with 10 functions and 10 lambdas.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your `error_list` and create the new series by comparing the given columns to your `reason`s (and cast to an `int` if you want 0 or 1 instead of False and True):

```
import pandas as pd

error_list = {
    "reason_one": "Reason One",
    "reason_two": "Reason Two",
    "reason_three": "Reason Three",
    "reason_four": "Reason Four",
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Labels": [
            "reason_two",
            "reason_two",
            "reason_one",
            "cat",
            "reason_four",
            "many",
            "sandwich",
        ]
    }
)

for reason, column_name in error_list.items():
    df[column_name] = (df["Labels"] == reason).astype(int)

print(df)
```

prints out

```
        Labels  Reason One  Reason Two  Reason Three  Reason Four
0   reason_two           0           1             0            0
1   reason_two           0           1             0            0
2   reason_one           1           0             0            0
3          cat           0           0             0            0
4  reason_four           0           0             0            1
5         many           0           0             0            0
6     sandwich           0           0             0            0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look at my question! This is helpful, but the Labels column can contain multiple values. So if we had 

`df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Labels": [
            "reason_two reason_one",
            "reason_two",
            "reason_one",
            "cat",
            "reason_four",
            "many",
            "sandwich",
        ]
    }
)`

I would want both Reason One and Reason Two to be true. Is there a way to do that type of comparison in-line without defining a function first?

Comment: Sure: `df["Labels"].str.contains(reason)`

Comment: TYVM!!! This is perfect, I greatly appreciate your help!!!!

Comment: @user20946655 Glad to help. Please remember to accept the answer using the checkbox next to the upvote thing. :)